Chipped enamel on tub flange
I am installing a porcelain enameled steel tub. In affixing the tub to studs, using wafer-head screws, I got over zealous and cracked the enamel on the tub flange.
As it stands, is this damage likely to lead to real problems down the road? If yes, is there anything I can do to mitigate such issues?
For what it’s worth, my plan is to install go board down to the top of the flange, and tile over it. Not sure if that makes a difference.


There may be rust that shows up in 20 to 30 years.
It would be prudent to paint the area with a rust preventative paint like Rust Oleum or something similar. Or a dab of polyurethane caulk.
